# Cached infinite prime generator

Tags: python, primes, generator

For a project I am working on, I need to use a lot of primes, frequently. To do this, I added a cache to [Will Ness's prime sieve](https://ideone.com/WFv4f), that stores already generated primes so getting them is quick. How can I improve this code?

```
def prime_sieve(): # postponed sieve, by Will Ness
    for c in (2,3,5,7):                     # original code David Eppstein,
        yield c
    sieve = {}                              # Alex Martelli, ActiveState Recipe 2002
    ps = prime_sieve()                      # a separate base Primes Supply:
    p = next(ps) and next(ps)               # (3) a Prime to add to dict
    q = p*p                                 # (9) its sQuare
    for c in count(9,2):                    # the Candidate
        if c in sieve:                      # c’s a multiple of some base prime
            s = sieve.pop(c)                # i.e. a composite ; or
        elif c < q:
            yield c                     # a prime
            continue
        else:   # (c==q):            # or the next base prime’s square:
            s=count(q+2*p,2*p)       #    (9+6, by 6 : 15,21,27,33,...)
            p=next(ps)               #    (5)
            q=p*p                    #    (25)
        for m in s:                  # the next multiple
            if m not in sieve:       # no duplicates
                break
        sieve[m] = s                 # original test entry: ideone.com/WFv4f

class cached_primes:
    def __init__(self):
        self.prime_gen = prime_sieve()
        self.vals = [2]
        next(self.prime_gen)

    def get(self, start=2, end=float('inf')):
        vals = self.vals

        lo = self.get_ind(start)
        if vals[-1] >= end:
            hi = self.get_ind(end)
            yield from islice(vals, lo, hi)
            return
        else:
            while vals[-1] < end:
                if len(vals) > lo:
                    bound = len(vals)
                    yield from takewhile(lambda p: p <=end, islice(vals, lo, bound))
                    lo = bound
                vals.append(next(self.prime_gen))
        hi = self.get_ind(end)
        yield from islice(vals, lo, hi)

    def get_ind(self, x):
        if x <= 2:
            return 0
        vals = self.vals
        B = x/log(x)
        if x < 17:
            return bisect(vals, x, 0, min(len(vals), int(B)))
        return bisect(vals, x, int(B), min(len(vals), int(1.25506*B)))
```

Comment: Can you add a link to the prime sieve solution on which your code is based?

Comment: ideone.com/WFv4f

Answer (score 4):

`prime_sieve()` isn't your code, so I won't review it (although I will express my opinion that it's in dire need of more commenting).

However, the choice to use it is firmly within the scope of this review, and frankly I can't understand it. The whole point of that particular implementation is to optimise memory use at the cost of considerable code complexity. But given that your goal is a fully cached list (i.e. optimising speed at the cost of memory usage), it would make far more sense to me to use a simpler implementation which directly accesses the cache.

---

> ```
>         if vals[-1] >= end:
>             hi = self.get_ind(end)
>             yield from islice(vals, lo, hi)
>             return
>         else:
>             while vals[-1] < end:
>                 if len(vals) > lo:
>                     bound = len(vals)
>                     yield from takewhile(lambda p: p <=end, islice(vals, lo, bound))
>                     lo = bound
>                 vals.append(next(self.prime_gen))
>         hi = self.get_ind(end)
>         yield from islice(vals, lo, hi)
> ```

Taking a step back to look at the structure, we have

```
        if condition():
            foo()
            return
        else:
            while not condition():
                bar()
        foo()
        return # implicit because it's the end of the function
```

Firstly,

```
            return
        else:
```

can often be clearer without the `else`, which is unnecessary: the scope it defines is unreachable if the `if` block executed. That gives

```
        if condition():
            foo()
            return

        while not condition():
            bar()
        foo()
        return
```

which is semantically identical to

```
        while not condition():
            bar()
        foo()
        return
```

---

> ```
>             while vals[-1] < end:
>                 if len(vals) > lo:
>                     bound = len(vals)
>                     yield from takewhile(lambda p: p <=end, islice(vals, lo, bound))
>                     lo = bound
>                 vals.append(next(self.prime_gen))
> ```

The whole `if` clause in here seems dubious to me. Why can't it be removed entirely? (I figured out the reason, but IMO there should be a comment to save me the effort).

Given that all but the first time round it will `yield from` a slice containing precisely one value (the one appended the previous time round), it seems rather heavyweight. It would probably make sense to refactor as:

```
    yield from (something)
    while vals[-1] < end:
        extension = next(self.prime_gen)
        vals.append(extension)
        yield extension
```

---

Further modification to the final refactors implemented for the above points may come from the simpler replacement of `prime_gen`. Do you want a replacement with produces primes one at a time, or something like a paged sieve? The latter should be more efficient, but at the cost of slight complication.

---

> ```
>     def get_ind(self, x):
> ```

If I had to guess without any contextual clues, I would assume that `ind` is short for *independent*. If it's necessary to abbreviate `index` then I consider `idx` to be the best option. But here there is a clear correct name for the method: `index`, for consistency with `list.index`.

(Of course, that's assuming you want it to be public. Given that it returns incorrect values for primes which haven't yet been reached by `get`, it would probably be better to call it `_index`).